# Change the position of the textbox validation

Tags: silverlight, validation, silverlight-3.0, textbox

The new data validation in silverlight 3 has a red textbox that flies out to the right.  This is a problem for me because I have have a textbox to the right that is getting covered by the popup.

How can I make this popup move somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retemplate the textbox.  The tooltip is found in there.  You can modify it using the placement property or margins to appear elsewhere.